# How to convert value data to another string data using pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I want to ask about how to convert data value to another data string from table 1 to table 2. Here's my explanation.

This is my function python program

```
def freq_action_requirement_measurement(keyword= stopwords_ucd1_topic.action, requirement= stopwords_freq_topic.requirement):
    disambiguation_df = []
    for angka in range(0, len(requirement)):
        a = [cosine_similarity(requirement[angka], keyword[num]) for num in range(0, len(keyword))]
        disambiguation_df.append(a)      
    hasil_disambiguation = pd.DataFrame(disambiguation_df, index= requirement, columns= keyword)
    return hasil_disambiguation
```

using that syntax, I called it

```
list_action_requirement3 = freq_action_requirement_measurement()
```

and get data like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z1Gfh.png)

I can get data from that table 1 to be table 2. That have been result such as Table usecase dan threshold value. Here's my code..

```
data_d1 = []
df_stop1 = stopwords_ucd1_topic
for idx, angka in enumerate(list_action_requirement3): 
  for jdx, num in enumerate(list_action_requirement3.iloc[:,idx]):
    if num >= 0.1:
      d1 = df_stop1[df_stop1.action == angka].iloc[0].usecase
      # d1 = len(df_stop1[df_stop1.action == angka])
      data_d1.append([d1, num])
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data_d1, columns= ['usecase', 'threshold'])
print(tabulate(df_b, headers = 'keys', tablefmt = 'psql'))
```

and the result, like this one..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9eld.png)

From that threshold value,  I wanna to change that value data to string data as a usecase data column. Like this one..

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzRGt.png)

Please help me soon, thank you..

Here's also another qna from another forum [qna](https://kotakode.com/pertanyaan/11246/Tanya-bagaimana-mengganti-data-dataframe-yang-ditentukan-dari-satu-data-ke-data-lain-berdasarkan-thr).

Comment: Please don't use images in your submission. You can easily copy/type them out so that we don't have to click through and see what is going on. If you do, you will get much better answers.

Comment: Thank you for your comment before, but I have a clue from another forum. But if you wanna answer my question. Would you come to visit at this link? I have another issue problem.. that should solve thank you..
https://kotakode.com/pertanyaan/11292/Bagaimana-merubah-dataframe-yang-disesuaikan-dengan-template-dataframe-yang-lain%3F